# Can an escript invoke another escript function?

Tags: erlang, escript

a.escript:

```
main(_)->
    b:read_config().
```

b.escript:

```
-module(b).
%% function exported
read_config()->
    %% read file
    io:format("hh~n").
```

If I convert the `b.escript` to `b.erl` and compile it to `b.beam`, it works.
But I don't want to compile manually.

Maybe I can insert `c:c(b)` like this:

```
main()->
    c:c(b),
    b:read_config().
```

Can't auto load the `b.escript` when useing like `b.eam`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible using `compile:file/1`

**a.escript**

```
%%This First line (i.e. the comment) MUST exist if we would like to call the script using 'escript <filename>', otherwise compilation error will occur. See 'https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html'
main([]) ->
    compile:file(b),
    b:read_config().
```

**b.erl**

```
-module(b).
-export([read_config/0]). %%Function MUST be exported, otherwise it will not be recognized from caller (e.g. escript )

read_config()->
    %% read file
    io:format("hh~n").
```

**Call from Shell**

```
$ escript a.escript
hh
```

Comment: I just used the 'b.hrl' .  It's partially solved my problem.